# ddply: pass geometric mean function

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I'm fairly new to ddply.  I'm trying to apply a geometric mean function to ddply, like so:

```
monthly.ave <- ddply(monthly,
           c("year", "month"), 
           summarise,
           mean = mean(abs.hrs.prop, na.rm=TRUE),
           median = median(abs.hrs.prop, na.rm=TRUE),
           geom.mean = geometric.mean(abs.hrs.prop, na.rm=TRUE))
```

ddply, of course, doesn't know geometric.mean.  So, how can I pass a geometric mean function to ddply?

Comment: Where did you get the `geometric.mean()` function?

Comment: `ddply` doesn't know `mean` or `median` either, it looks for them in the global environment and attached namespaces (packages you have loaded). As long as `geometric.mean()` is a function you've defined or it's defined in a package you've loaded, it's fine.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't have a function for geometric.mean (at least not yet)

Comment: so create a `geometric.mean` function and then pass that to `ddply`. Search Stack Overflow on how to create geometric mean function in r.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you a list of potential relevant function to calculate a geometric mean.

```
library(sos)
findFn("geometric mean")
```